# Mais de uma query em uma requisição muito lenta na primeira requisição em C#

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net

Tenho um método que requisita dados ao banco e neste mesmo método eu chamo um outro método que também faz requisição ao banco (mySql).

```
public class Viagem
{
    public int idViagem { get; set; }
    ...
    public Cidade origem { get; set; } 

public List<Viagem> getViagens(int p)
{
    Connection con = new Connection();
    string query = @"SELECT * FROM viagem"
    if (con.connect())
    {
          using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, con.getConnection()))
          {
              MySqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

              while (reader.Read())
              {
                  Viagem viagem = new Viagem();
                  Cidade cidade = new Cidade();
                  ...
                  viagem.origem = cidade.getCidade(Convert.toInt32(reader["cidade"]));
              }
     }
```

}

O método getCidade tem o comportamento parecido com este getViagens.
Então quando tenho chamadas assim aninhadas está demorando muito no servidor da GODADDY, tenho códigos parecidos em outros servidores o problema não acontece.
Está demorando mais de 30 segundos para me retornar 20 instâncias.

Preciso configurar algo no servidor para ele fazer pooling corretamente?

**Editado:** O problema ocorre sempre quando faço a primeira requisição, as outras, mesmo que os valores mudem, ocorre em um tempo esperado. Alguma sugestão?

**Resolvido:** A godaddy fixa o tempo de sessão em 5 minutos, desconectando os usuários não ativos por este tempo, por isso a primeira requisição sempre demorava muito, o servidor tendo que sair do "standby" para só então fazer a requisição. A solução vou criar uma tarefa dentro da própria hospedagem para que ficasse fazendo requisição de uma página qualquer a cada 4 minutos e mantivesse o servidor "acordado".

[Criar task godaddy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25467537/asmx-task-scheduler-on-godaddy)

Comment: Já rodou essa query diretamente no banco e verificou se o tempo está demorando?

Comment: Cara, isso acontece comigo, uso o Godaddy e por incrivel que pareço eu tenho varios metodos iguais aos seu, no LOCALHOST fica lendo, agora quando eu passo para produção, ele vai rapidinho. Se for ASP.NET e você tiver rodando no localhost é normal isso acontecer.

Comment: O ideal seria você executar essa query diretamente no banco de dados para verificar se o problema está no banco ou na sua aplicação. Depois disso poderíamos tentar ajudar com a solução mais adequada para o seu problema.

Comment: As querys diretamente no banco, inclusive todas juntas usando join funcionam rapidamente. E tenho o mesmo problema em produção.

Comment: Você contratou uma VPS ou um aplicação para asp.net? Em resumo, tem acesso ao IIS ou somente via painel ou deploy?

Comment: Após a primeira chamada tudo fica normal, correto?

Comment: Sim, tudo ficava normal, o problema estava no encerramento do pool na godaddy.